# How to get Location user with CLLocationManager in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have this code on my view controller but this not working:

```
  import UIKit
  import CoreLocation

  class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   var location: CLLocationManager!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     location=CLLocationManager()
     location.delegate = self
     location.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest
     location.startUpdatingLocation()
 }

  func locationManager(location:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject[]) {
     println("locations = \(locations)")
     label1.text = "success"
 }
```

I have the permissions how I read in other post. but I don't obtain never, no println..

Thanks!!

Comment: This works for me
Its a simple example See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35973586/3410437

Answer (score 19):

first add this two line in plist file

1) `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

2) `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Then this is class working complete implement this

```
import UIKit 
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var seenError : Bool = false
var locationFixAchieved : Bool = false
var locationStatus : NSString = "Not Started"

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    initLocationManager();
    return true
}

// Location Manager helper stuff
func initLocationManager() {
    seenError = false
    locationFixAchieved = false
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.locationServicesEnabled
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}

// Location Manager Delegate stuff

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if (error) {
        if (seenError == false) {
            seenError = true
           print(error)
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: AnyObject[]!) {
    if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
        locationFixAchieved = true
        var locationArray = locations as NSArray
        var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
        var coord = locationObj.coordinate

        println(coord.latitude)
        println(coord.longitude)
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        var shouldIAllow = false

        switch status {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
            locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            locationStatus = "Status not determined"
        default:
            locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
            shouldIAllow = true
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
        if (shouldIAllow == true) {
            NSLog("Location to Allowed")
            // Start location services
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello. I did everything that you wrote but CLAuthorizationStatus.status is always NotDetermined. why?

Comment: please check in your setting > yourapp > location permission

Comment: **'locationServicesEnabled' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift**

Comment: + terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. How to fix that?

Comment: @jayeshkavathiya Why do you need to put the code in the AppDelegate class?

Comment: so we can access location to full app. we not need to declare again if you need in one another class. you can use as per your requirement. if you want in only one class then put this code in single class

Comment: @jayeshkavathiya can you fix your code, please? I can't understand, why that does not work.

Comment: @tim - Replace that line with this         CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()

Answer (score 5):

Following are the simple steps for getting user location in Swift 3

1) First add this line in plist file with description

```
 NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

2) Add CoreLocation.framework in your project(Under section Build Phases-> Link Binary With Library)

3) In AppDelegate class

```
   import CoreLocation
```

4)  Create locationManager Object as follows

```
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
```

5) Write following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

6) Confirm CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate like as follows

```
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

7) Write CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate method for getting user location

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    print("location error is = \(error.localizedDescription)")

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!


    print("Current Locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're declaring location as an explicitly unwrapped optional (CLLocationManager!) it requires an initializer, either in an init method as suggested by jhurray, or just inline, as:

```
var location: CLLocationManager! = nil
```

Note that you've got other possible problems as well, including that iOS 8 has new requirements for querying the user for permission to use CoreLocation.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024116/cllocationmanager-authorizationstatus-always-clauthorizationstatus-notdetermin/24078863#24078863) for more information.

Comment: I have permissions but I don't know  if i have all.. But I can see with a break point that don't enter to the function                    func locationManager(location:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject[]) {
    println("locations = \(locations)")
    label1.text = "success"
} Why don't use this function my app??

Comment: Check the other link and make sure you're both making the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization/requestAlwaysAuthorization` call and setting the right key in Info.plist.also,check that your making the right calls to start the manager.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same code as above but cleaned up to work with Swift as of the date of this posting.  This worked for me.

Kudos to the original poster.

(note, stick this into whatever class you will use to handle your location stuff.)

```js
var lastLocation = CLLocation()
var locationAuthorizationStatus:CLAuthorizationStatus!
var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var seenError : Bool = false
var locationFixAchieved : Bool = false
var locationStatus : NSString = "Not Started"

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    
    self.initLocationManager()
    
}
    // Location Manager helper stuff
    func initLocationManager() {
        seenError = false
        locationFixAchieved = false
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    
    // Location Manager Delegate stuff
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if ((error) != nil) {
            if (seenError == false) {
                seenError = true
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
            locationFixAchieved = true
            var locationArray = locations as NSArray
            var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
            var coord = locationObj.coordinate
            
            println(coord.latitude)
            println(coord.longitude)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,  didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            var shouldIAllow = false
            
            switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                locationStatus = "Status not determined"
            default:
                locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
                shouldIAllow = true
            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
            if (shouldIAllow == true) {
                NSLog("Location to Allowed")
                // Start location services
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            } else {
                NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
            }
    }
```

Comment: How to get user old location @Wade?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by old location.  Do you mean the last location you were at?

Comment: `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` the above method is in Objective c. I need exact replacement for above method with same params.

Answer (score 1):

Do following stuff in viewcontroller [Using swift] -

```
  class ViewController:     
  UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {


  var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
  var usersCurrentLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined{
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager?.distanceFilter = 200
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    startUpdatingLocation()

    usersCurrentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LATTITUDE, LONGITUDE)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(usersCurrentLocation!, span)
    mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    mapview.delegate = self
    mapview.showsUserLocation = true

}
```

//MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate methods

```
func startUpdatingLocation() {
    self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func stopUpdatingLocation() {
    self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

// MARK: MKMapViewDelegate

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation){
    mapview.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location!.coordinate
    mapview.showsUserLocation = true
    regionWithGeofencing()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have init functions.

Override init(coder:) and init(nibName: bundle:) and add any custom init you want.

Because you have said that location is not optional, you must initialize it before your super init calls in ALL of your init functions.

```
func init() {
...
location = CLLocationManager()
// either set delegate and other stuff here or in viewDidLoad
super.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
// other initialization below

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be written as 
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {