# iOS App Location Permission is not Working Currently

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

It is my general ViewController class , I research the this question  [iOS app doesn't ask for location permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497928/ios-app-doesnt-ask-for-location-permission?noredirect=1&lq=1)  , I already have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

```
@IBOutlet weak var ownMapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager();


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    guard status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse else
    {
        print("Location not using");
        return;
    }

    print("Location using.");
    ownMapView.showsUserLocation = true;
    }
```

Even I added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` this is not working for me . It prints only "Location not using"

How do I request correctly ?

Comment: At first run the status should be "NotDetermined" and you should get a permission popup. Did you get that popup?

Comment: The first trying I choose the not Allowing option , then the program never ask the location allow request .

Comment: I mean first running of the application

Comment: Try by removing the app from device/simulator and run it again

Comment: I am now trying to remove and run it again

Comment: Sir , thanks to answer , I tried and it worked for me , I checked your answer as a Correct but  i have another Question . When ı retry the app , firstly print the Location Not using then I allowed the Request then it prints Location using . What do you think about this situation ?

Comment: Happy to help! I am posting the reply as an answer shortly, accept if it helps.

Comment: Yes , I am waiting for this , Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this correctly check the CLLAuthorizationStatus doc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CLAuthorizationStatus

CLAuthorizationStatus has several possible values:

- NotDetermined - User has not yet made a decision to allow/deny to use location
- Restricted - App is restricted to use location
- Denied - User has denied to use location.
- AuthorizedAlways - This app is authorized to start location services at any time.
- AuthorizedWhenInUse - App is authorized to start most location services while running in the foreground

You are checking only "AuthorizedWhenInUse" status but you launch first its status is NotDetermined.

You can further check the status like below:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status  == .NotDetermined
        {
            print ("Loction use not determined")
            return
        }
        if status  == .Denied
        {
            print ("Location determined")
            return
        }
        guard status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse else
        {
            print("Location not using");
            return;
        }

        print("Location using.");
        ownMapView.showsUserLocation = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Have us added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription & NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in plist? . Add these and it will work .

Comment: "I already have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" - He already did that

Comment: Yes sir , I have added these Two Description

Answer (score 0):

For those coming to this in iOS 16+:
I had difficulty getting the prompt to appear while trying to get access to "Always and When in use" permissions.

What worked for me was a frustrating combination of things. First, using the "When in use" string in the .plist. `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`

Then, requesting permissions with the "always auth" method.

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Listen for that change with this delegate function:

```
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Location authorization status: Not Determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("Location authorization status: Restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("Location authorization status: Denied")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("Location authorization status: Authorized Always")
            manager.requestLocation()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Location authorization status: Auth'd when in use")
            manager.requestLocation()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .authorized:
            print("Location authorization status: Authorized")
            manager.requestLocation()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("Unknown location authorization case")
        }
    }
```

When you or the user is prompted by the OS, the only options that will appear are `Allow Once` and `Allow When Used`.

If you or your user to `Allow When Used` the authorizationState will be `.authorizedAlways`, and that case will be called. It was very frustrating to learn this, because is doesn't exactly add up between the UI and the actual permissions.