# CLLocationManager with Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I followed the instructions in:
[How to get Location user whith CLLocationManager in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252645/how-to-get-location-user-whith-cllocationmanager-in-swift) and I was able to get the coordinates in my iPhone but not in the emulator. once I run the app in the emulator I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

The sample code in the previous link is showing how to get the coordination within the AppDelegate file.

As I am a beginner in iPhone development, I couldn't retrieve coordinates in the viewController.

I would like to keep the app notified as the mobile is moving and the coordination is changed and need to calculate how far (kilometers or miles) the mobile from a specific location (fixed coordination).

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in beta 5 with location and the simulator.

Check the release notes issue - 17858614

Comment: Ok, I could keep testing with my mobile, any help in keeping my app updated with real location all the time?

Comment: @loC if you're frustrated by the GPS taking too long to "warm up" with an initial location fix while indoors/with bad signal, I suggest installing a GPS app such as `MotionX GPS` and having it record a track in the background while you're doing development. That will keep the GPS active in the background ensuring the GPS hardware is always active.

Comment: @loc, how do you mean updated in realtime do you mean moving about?

Comment: I mean that the application will show how far or close you are from a fixed position as you are moving. For example: showing the distance between you and your office.

Answer (score 0):

on the iOS simulator under Debug menu, change location from Apple to something like City Bicycle Ride and give it a run.