# Swift CLAuthorizationStatus always is CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I want my application get user`s location.
i did everything from right answer from [How to get Location user whith CLLocationManager in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252645/how-to-get-location-user-whith-cllocationmanager-in-swift)
but CLAuthorizationStatus always is CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined 
What is the problem?

Comment: did you ever solved it?

Comment: Yes. first add this two line in plist file

1) NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

2) NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  - From link in my question

Comment: Solved it myself... I added the two keys in the `plist` for my test-cases instead of my application's `plist`

Answer (score 0):

be careful  that

> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

and

> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

keys are mandatory, so you should include that in your plist.