# get user location and updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am trying to get user location in my iPhone app. It has specified in info.plist needed permission (use location even if app is not offline). But still I do not see that my delegate is triggered at least once meaning I do not get even current location. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager();
override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
    }

    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
    let long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;


    print(lat)
 }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Could somebody point me out possible problems?

Comment: It is ask for location permission or not?

Comment: yes, it asked for permission once and I allowed. Every next program run I do not get this permission request since it is stored in settings. Thing is that delegate which should be triggered on location update is not actually called. I suspect this could be multithreading issue e.g. calling from main thread and on other thread that instance does not exists... checking now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Location user whith CLLocationManager in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252645/how-to-get-location-user-whith-cllocationmanager-in-swift)

Comment: Are you running on a device or on the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` in `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)`. It should work.